# c++ primer 4th edition - String question

Tags: c++

I'm reading page 86 in this book about string and literals and i don't understand why it says the following about string s1 and s2.

```
string s1("hello, ");  
string s2("world\n");  
string s3 = s1+s2;  
..
```

it says `s1` and `s2` included punctuation directly. Punctuation? What punctuation.

Also on page 87.

```
string s1 = "hello"; // no punctuation. Again what punctuation?
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: s3 will be "hello, world\n" where \n is a new line - The punctuation is the ','

Comment: Some linguist must have written this man.

Comment: @yapkm01: Should we expect future questions as you progress through the book?

Comment: @phooji - i hope you guys don't mind me asking stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually went in and looked at the book in question. The author is considering the "," and the "\n" to be "punctuation."

The very next sentence on page 86 said:

```
The strings s1 and s2 included punctuation directly. 
We could achieve the same result by mixing string objects 
and string literals as follows:

string s1("hello");
string s2("world");
string s3 = s1 + ", " + s2 + "\n";
```

-- Dan

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the author means that commas `,` and linefeeds`\n` are punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

Keith's and Jason's answer are correct referring to the "comma" punctuation. In s1 the "," is included with "hello". This could also be written as: 
string s3 = s1 + ", " + s2 + "\n";  separating the punctuation

edit-Looks like Dan already posted the same answer.